# How to route form one page to another page in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Here I'm developing moving from one page to another page in `IONIC`. So that I developed below code

```
<div *ngFor="let list of product">
  <img [src] ='list.imge'/>
  <button ion-button round (click)="Contact()">view</button>
</div>
```

and `typescript` is

```
export class HomePage {
 product:any[]=[{id:121,name:"iphone",imge:'assets/img/iphone.png'}]
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
  Contact() {
    this.navCtrl.push('ContactPage');
  }
}
```

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: ContactPage
>       at c (polyfills.js:3)

Once I click on view button it is not moving to another page.

**Edit**
contactpage type script

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `(click)="Contact()"`? (with round brackets `()` after the function)

Comment: change `(click)="Contact"` to `(click)="Contact()"`.

Comment: @TheUnreal I have change but there is an error

Comment: @Kaddath I have tried there is an error

Comment: see my question is updated

Answer (score 1):

in case it's lazy loaded:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
// IMPORT ContactPage IF NOT LAZY-LOADED
import { ContactPage} from path;

export class HomePage {
    constructor(private navCtrl:NavController){}

    // IF LAZY-LOADED
    Contact(){
        this.navCtrl.push('ContactPage');
    }

    // IF NOT LAZY-LOADED
    Contact(){
        this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: it causing lazy loaded , it works good now. I changed code thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Your **ContactPage** should contain module. Is that created using ionic page generate command? 
Reference link: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/

You can push a page for navigation using two ways.

1) Import page in page does not contain a module. And navigate like :

```
import { ContactPage } from path;
this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage);
```

2) If a page has a module, navigate like:

```
this.navCtrl.push('ContactPage');
```

Comment: I did same what you mentioned but still showing some error

Comment: @GonnaHack, can you please update ContactPage typescript.And does it include module.ts?

Comment: I have added please check it

Comment: Yeah it is include in module.ts like `import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';`  and in the command prompt it is showing like `All imports on this line are unused.

       L2:  import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
       L3:  import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let list of product">
  <img [src] ='list.imge'/>
  <button ion-button round (click)="Contact()">view</button>
</div>
```

Modify your Typescript like this

```
import { ContactPage} from '../../pages/contact/contact';
.......

    export class HomePage {
     product:any[]=[{id:121,name:"iphone",imge:'assets/img/iphone.png'}]
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      }

      Contact() {
        this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage);
        OR
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(ContactPage);//(if you want block backbutton)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have imported Contact page page but there is an error like invalid contact page

Comment: please delete your current contact page and run this command"ionic generate page Contact"....then added to module and import to places whether you needed